# What is maximal value of int on 64 bit GCC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, int, unsigned-integer

I wonder what is the greatest unsigned int value of 64 bit GCC on Linux. 
On 32 bit GCC, it's 4 294 967 295. 
I have only 32 bit machines so I can't check it.

Comment: You can check it on wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Signed: From −9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807,
Unsigned: From 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 which equals 2^(64) − 1

Comment: [`std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>:max();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) - I wouldn't hard code it anywhere, use the standard solution!

Comment: `unsigned int` is most likely *still* 32 bits; you haven't specified the architecture or ABI.

Answer (score 4):

You could find out this value by using the macro `UINT_MAX`, defined in `limits.h`.